# MySql Restoring issue:Stored procedure not Restored

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql, restore

I have a MySQL dump having all routines. When I restored, only stored procedures haven't got restored. The MySQL version from where i took Dump is 5.0.77-log and the version to which I restored is 5.6.12.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Did server host has changed, ? my mean did you ported db from one host to another or trying on same host in diffrent db.

**b/c it might be that if you changed db from one server to another then, you have to chnage you definer in stored proocedure, if it is defined."Definer" is like DEFINER = 'admin'@'localhost' in sp**,
.

check this in you stored procedure. if it is not a issue , let me know.[More about definer...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-security.html)

Comment: yes, server host has changed.I tried by adding a user specified in the Definer and tried restoring just the routines,but got error like 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Might be , you have applied multiple trigger on a table, but mysql does not support this upto mysql 5.7.check this, [check bug link on mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10)

Answer (score 0):

I got here as none of my Mariadb stored procedures and functions would restore (ran the SQL in the dump file manually)  It just errored out on all procs and functions.  I replaced the DELIMITER ;; that was set in my file with $$ and it would restore. The tables and views restored without any issue. The backup did move hosts and I also changed the definer as it changed user/IP.